# How to rotate two shapes around two different points with Graphics2D?

Tags: java, geometry, graphics2d

I'm trying to make a quadcopter like shape, so I have to rotate different shapes around different points.

The following snippet works for the first rectangle and not the second.

```
public void render(Graphics2D g) {
    // cx and cy is the center of the shape these spin near

    // add prop rotation
    at = g.getTransform();
    at.rotate(Math.toRadians(prop_rotation), cx, cy-42);
    g.setTransform(at);

    // Rect 1 spins correctly!
    g.fillRect(cx-14, cy-45, 28, 6);

    at = g.getTransform();
    at.rotate(Math.toRadians(prop_rotation), cx, cy+38);
    g.setTransform(at);
    // Rect 2 spins around rect 1
    g.fillRect(cx-14, cy+35, 28, 6);
}
```

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yEz9.png)

So how do I do this with multiple centers?

Answer (score 1):

Transformations are accumlitive.

Start by grabbing a copy of the `Graphics` context and modifying it in isolation...

```
Graphics2D copy = (Graphics2D)g.create();
at = copy.getTransform();
at.rotate(Math.toRadians(prop_rotation), cx, cy-42);
copy.setTransform(at);

// Rect 1 spins correctly!
copy.fillRect(cx-14, cy-45, 28, 6);
copy.dispose();

Graphics2D copy = (Graphics2D)g.create();
at = copy.getTransform();
at.rotate(Math.toRadians(prop_rotation), cx, cy+38);
copy.setTransform(at);
// Rect 2 spins around rect 1
copy.fillRect(cx-14, cy+35, 28, 6);
copy.dispose();
```

This basically makes a copy of the `Graphics` properties, but still allows you to paint to the same "surface".  Changing the copies properties won't affect the originals.

An alternative might be to transform the shape itself...

```
private Rectangle housing1;
//...
housing1 = new Rectangle(28, 6);

//...

AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
at.translate(cx - 14, cy - 45);
at.rotate(Math.toRadians(prop_rotation), cx, cy - 42);
Shape s1 = at.createTransformedShape(housing1);
g.fill(housing1);
```

This way, you don't mess with the `Graphics` context (which is always nice) and you gain a handy little piece which could be re-used, example, for the other side...

```
at = new AffineTransform();
at.translate(cx-14, cy+35);
at.rotate(Math.toRadians(prop_rotation), cx, cy + 38);
Shape s2 = at.createTransformedShape(housing1);
g.fill(housing2);
```